# Bad shape in LSTM model

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm using ***tensorflow js*** and I have this code to build my model of recurrent neural network to a classification problem with 3 classes, instances of size 250, .
I have the following error message when I try to fit my model:

***Error: Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense1 to have shape [,3], but got array with shape [4827,1].***

I pretty new to construct my own model in tfjs, and I think I messed up with tensor shapes

PS: my dataset contains 4827 instances and my embeddingSize is 32

```
function buildModel(maxLen, vocabularySize, embeddingSize, numClasses)
{
   const model = tensorflow.sequential();

   model.add(tensorflow.layers.embedding(
      {
         inputDim: vocabularySize,
         outputDim: embeddingSize,//embeddingSize = 32
         inputLength: maxLen//maxLen = 250
      }));

   model.add(tensorflow.layers.lstm({units: embeddingSize/*, returnSequences: true*/}));

   model.add(tensorflow.layers.dense({units: numClasses, activation: 'softmax'}));//numClasses = 3
   return model;
}
```

```
const history = await model.fit(data, labels, {
   epochs: epochs,
   batchSize: batchSize,
   validationSplit: validationSplit,
   callbacks: () =>
   {
      console.log("Coucou");
   }
});
console.log(history);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my data which had label un 1D format (0, 1 or 2) instead of having 3D format ([1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1])

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the layers dimension by returning `false` to the lstm layer

```
model.add(tensorflow.layers.lstm({units: embeddingSize, returnSequences: false}));
```

Comment: Your answer is right but it's not the main reason why it didn't work.

Comment: You error is about the dense layer. You can get rid of the issue by using a 3d tensor layer - actually you just need to match the dimension shape of the layer either by flattening the input layer or change the dimension of the label. But I will rather choose to flatten my input layer instead which is more common thing to do.